# Merge two directories keeping any files with same name

Tags: powershell

I am looking for some help to create a PowerShell script to merge or copy one directory to another that the destination directory has files with the same name as the source.

I need to keep both, the script can append a number to the source file if it has a file of duplicate name in the destination.

[Here](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/copy-individual-files-and-rename-duplicates/) is a sample script that deals with one file, but I need to set a directory and let it loose recursively on the entire directory.

```
$SourceFile = "C:\Temp\File.txt"
$DestinationFile = "C:\Temp\NonexistentDirectory\File.txt"

if ((Test-Path $DestinationFile) -eq $false) {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $DestinationFile -Force
}

Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far with examples of the data to deal with and expected results. BTW - `cmd` is an `.exe` - `.com` files have been disabled for a long time.

Comment: im changing the question to use powershell, thanks, i dont have any code so far but i do have some examples. i'll post that if its ok to post others work

Comment: Are there subfolders? Shall they also be moved. What if a file has already an affixed number, increase that number or put another affix? Should the affix be separated with an underscore or enclosed in parentheses `(1)` I wouldn't copy but move/rename the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$SourceDir = "C:\Temp"
$DestinationDir = "C:\Temp2\NonexistentDirectory"

#create dir if not exists (dont remove if exist)
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $DestinationDir -Force

#get list files destination dir 
$DestinationFiles=gci $DestinationDir -File

#loop on file source and create newname for copy while name exist already
gci $SourceDir -File | %{

$counter=0
$name=$_.Name
while ($name -in $DestinationFiles.Name)
{
  $counter++;
  $name="{0}_{1:d6}{2}" -f  $_.BaseName, $counter, $_.Extension

}


Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$DestinationDir\$name" 

}
```